# Integrate and plot a piecewise function in Sagemath

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to integrate a piecewise function using Sagemath, and finding it to be impossible. My original code is below, but it's wrong due to accidental evaluation described [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_functions.html).

```
def f(x):
    if(x < 0):
        return 3 * x + 3
    else:
        return -3 * x + 3

g(x) = integrate(f(t), t, 0, x)
```

The fix for plotting mentioned on the website is to use `f` instead of `f(t)`, but this is apparently unsupported for the `integrate()` function since a `TypeError` is raised.

Is there a fix for this that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining a piecewise function via `def`, use the built-in [piecewise class](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/piecewise.html):

```
f = Piecewise([[(-infinity, 0), 3*x+3],[(0, infinity), -3*x+3]]) 
f.integral()
```

Output:

```
Piecewise defined function with 2 parts, [[(-Infinity, 0), x |--> 3/2*x^2 + 3*x], [(0, +Infinity), x |--> -3/2*x^2 + 3*x]]
```

The piecewise functions have their own methods, such as `.plot()`. Plotting does not support infinite intervals, though. A plot can be obtained with finite intervals

```
f = Piecewise([[(-5, 0), 3*x+3],[(0, 5), -3*x+3]]) 
g = f.integral()
g.plot()
```

But you also want to subtract g(0) from g. This is not as straightforward as g-g(0), but not too bad, either: get the list of pieces with `g.list()`, subtract g(0) from each function, then recombine.

```
g0 = Piecewise([(piece[0], piece[1] - g(0)) for piece in g.list()])
g0.plot()
```

And there you have it:

[image: plot]

By extending this approach, we don't even need to put finite intervals in f from the beginning. The following plots g - g(0) on a given interval [a,b], by modifying the domain:

```
a = -2
b = 3
g0 = Piecewise([((max(piece[0][0], a), min(piece[0][1], b)), piece[1] - g(0)) for piece in g.list()])
g.plot()
```

[image: plotrange]

Comment: I've looked into the Piecewise class, and it honestly seems to be next to useless. It doesn't extend the functionality of expressions, so I can't do basic things like add a constant or use it as part of another expression. As a result, I can't accomplish my original goal of plotting the definite integral, since I would need to subtract g(0).

Comment: I now explained how to subtract a constant.

Comment: The bottom line is: the class is underdeveloped, but one can do more with it by dropping down to Python list level, and coming back.

Comment: Thanks! The whole Piecewise class still seems like a hack though, and having to redefine a function each time I want to plot it is a bit annoying. At the very least, the plot function should be extended to include optional left and right bounds. I've also figured how to solve this using Python functions, which I will post as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the Piecewise class, this can easily be fixed by defining `g(x)` as a Python function as well:

```
def f(x):
    if(x < 0):
        return 3 * x + 3
    else:
        return -3 * x + 3

def g(x):
    (y, e) = integral_numerical(f, 0, x)
    return y
```

Then `plot(g)` works just fine.